# Probability of convergence of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

> Prove that the probability of convergence of a sequence of independent random variables(Let's say $\{X_n\}$) is equal to zero or one. (Kai Lai Chung: Page82. 12, *A course in probability theory*)
>
> If $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables not constant a.e., then $\mathbb P\{X_n\text{ converges}\}=0$. (Kai Lai Chung: Page82. 13, *A course in probability theory*)

---

I am trying to solve the above exercises. We should first show that $\mathbb P\{X_n\text{ converges}\}=0$ or $1$. Indeed, it suffices to show that for every $\varepsilon>0$, $\{|X_n-X_{n'}|>\varepsilon:n,n'\in\mathbb{N}, n\ne n'\}$ are pairwise independent. Then by the corollary of Borel-Cantelli Lemma, we will be able to show the first exercise. However, this seemingly obvious fact is giving me a hard time to formulate it rigorously.

Comment: Do you know Kolmogorov $0$-$1$ law?

Comment: @Zhanxiong I haven't learned the Kolmogorov $0$-$1$ law yet. Neither am I supposed to use it I think. The book has not yet introduced the Kolmogorov $0$-$1$ law at this point.

Comment: It's not something particularly difficult -- only a good understanding of independence of sigma fields is needed. I am not sure if this problem can be solved without touching the notion of "tail sigma field".

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thank you for your comment! I think I would come back to this exercise later perhaps after learning the zero-one laws.

Answer (score 1):

They are not pairwise independent: e.g. $X_1 - X_2$ and $X_1 - X_3$ are (in general) not independent, their covariance is the variance of $X_1$.  What is true is that the event that the sequence converges is independent of $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N)$ for any $N$.